# How to select all div from body and not from the header?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementsbytagname

I use this javascript code in order to select all DIVs and change their color. I don't want to change color of the DIV in the header. Purpose of this task is to learn HTML5, DOM, Javascript and getElementsByTagName function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>test</title>
    <div>divv in header</div>
</head>
<body onload="Onload()">
    <div>bla</div>
    <div id="Div1">bla</div>
    <div id="Div2">bla
        <div id="Div4">div in div</div>
    </div>
    <div id="Div3" class="diiiivvv">bla</div>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function Onload() {
        var h = document.head;
        var dh = h.getElementsByTagName('div');
        if (dh.length != 0) {
            dh[0].style.backgroundColor = 'red'; //fail
        }            

        var d = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

        for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
            d[i].style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
        };
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why is there a DIV in the head?

Comment: Div elements aren't allowed in the head. Your browser is likely doing error correction and moving it to the start of the body.

Comment: I think you're confused by HTML5's new <header> element - this is **not** the same as the <head> element!

Answer (score 0):

Where is your problem? You just did it right to select the div in head:

```
    var h = document.head;
    var dh = h.getElementsByTagName('div');
    // or short:
    var dh = document.head.getElementsByTagName('div');
```

So why don't you use the same for the body element:

```
    var db = document.body.getElementsByTagName('div');
```

The [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) method can be applied on any dom element.

Comment: `head` is not a standard property of `document` objects until HTML5, so may not be supported by many browsers.

Comment: Really? Good to know. But irrelevant here, OP wanted document.body.

Comment: It's relevant because it's in your answer.

Comment: var db = document.body.getElementsByTagName('div');
        for (var i = 0; i < db.length; i++) {
            db[i].style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
        };

Comment: Bergi, problem is that div in the header is getting selected too and I don't want it.

Comment: No, it will not if you use document.body. But use your DOM inspector to look up whether RobG was right in his comment on your question.

Answer (score 0):

You may find it best to access the required elements using a CSS selector and appropriate style rule. Here's an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function applyRule(selectorText, value) {

  // Get the style sheets - note sytleSheets is a live HTMLCollection
  var sheet, sheets = document.styleSheets;

  // Add a style sheet if there isn't one in the document
  if (!sheets.length) {
    sheet = document.createElement('style');
    sheet.type = 'text/css';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(sheet);
  }

  // Get the last style sheet
  sheet = sheets[sheets.length - 1];

  // Add the rule - W3C model
  if (sheet.insertRule) {
    sheet.insertRule(selectorText + ' {' + value + '}', sheet.cssRules.length);

  // IE model
  } else if (sheet.addRule) {
    sheet.addRule(selectorText, value, sheet.rules.length);
  }  
}
</script>

<div>here is a div
<button onclick="applyRule('div','background-color: red')">Change div background colour</button>
</div>
```